# Mongo Aggregate query - Strings that qualify for substring range append 3 dots only

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The following MongoDB query retrieves the title and the first 50 characters of the summary field:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {$match:{_id:ObjectId("642617b84b1f458a6c895c64")}},
    {$project:{_id:0, title:1, summary:{$substrBytes:["$summary", 0, 50]} }}
])
```

Is there any way in this query where I could append three dots ... to the summaries which qualified for the substring range, i.e. summary string length is greater than 50 characters but no 3 dots ... to the summaries which didn't fall in the range, i.e. the summary string length is less than 50 characters?

e.g.

summary less than 50 characters displayed as: "Follows Catwoman in an attempt"

summary more than 50 characters: "Generally fair conditions with a few showers developing by late morning. There is a low chance..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("642617b84b1f458a6c895c64")
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "title": 1,
      "summary": {
        "$cond": [
          {"$lte": [{"$strLenCP": "$summary"}, 50]},
          "$summary",
          {
            "$concat": [
              {"$substrCP": ["$summary", 0, 50]},
              "..."
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vGaZNGasrHN).